# Elasticsearch group sorted combined query

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, grouping

I am faced with the following issue. I have a few sorted queries against a specific group of records in my index, similar to the one below, where the `term1` matching values vary per query, while for `term2` they remain static for all queries.

```
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "terms": {
                    "term1": [ "val1", "val2" ]   
                }
            },
            "must_not": {
                "terms": {
                    "term2": [ "val3", "val4" ]   
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        { "sort_term": "desc" }
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}
```

Right now, I'm performing all these queries separately and then combining and shuffling their results in code, something that as you can probably tell is not ideal. I was wondering if there's a way to combine these queries in ElasticSearch, while maintaining the group-based sorting.

The reason I want to maintain the sorting order of each individual query is because the sorting values are not uniform and I don't want results from different groups to be buried down the result set.

The only solution I could think of would be to somehow re-process all records and compute a relative sorting value based on the sorting values of all the records in a given group, but these values change very regularly and the index has a lot of records, so that would probably be overkill.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple Terms in sort array. If you combine the query I would first sort by _type, which prevents mixing up your search results. The sort field of your query should be like:

```
"sort": [
    { "_type": "desc" },
    { "sort_term_query1": "desc" },
    { "sort_term_query2": "desc" },
],
```

Comment: I understand that I can use multiple sorting terms, but in this case all my queries use the same sorting term. What I want to do is individually sort every boolean term, and mix the results.

Comment: Then I did not understand your question, its unclear how the end result should be sorted.